# Not able to connect to AKS cluster on Ubuntu console but powershell works

Tags: powershell, ubuntu-18.04, azure-aks

In Ubuntu 18.4 console on Windows 10 machine, I have run below command to connects AKS cluster to fetch node information,

```
az Login
```

Then fetching cluster credential,

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group <resource_group_name> --name <cluster_name>
```

I can see kube config file `C:\Users\XXX\.kube\config` is created with the right AKS cluster information also I don't have any local cluster running on my machine.

But when I am trying to get `node` information for AKS cluster, it's trying to connect `localhost:8080`

```
 :/mnt/c/Users/XXX$ kubectl get nodes
 The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right 
 host or port?
```

But the same working from `PowerShell console`. What settings I am missing for `Ubuntu`?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested in my environment. The reason for the error is .kube/config file is created in the windows but not in the ubuntu. The .kube/config file needs to be copied to ubuntu.

Please use the below command to copy the config file from your windows machine to ubuntu :

```
cp /mnt/c/Users/[USERNAME]/.kube/config ~/.kube/config
```

Use below command to switch to the aks cluster :

```
kubectl config use-context [cluster-name]
```

Now, you should be able to get the node information of your cluster using :

```
kubectl get nodes
```

Please refer below screenshot :

[image]